# running an script only for an specific time

Tags: android, schedule, timertask

I have a code for detecting location that I want to works only for 2 minutes.

when I fire start() method script must works almost for 2 minutes.

problem is in there that how run my script only for an specific time.
I used this code but don't running correct.

don't fire stop() method from in Timer().schedule()

```
public class a implements LocationListener{
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private Location lastloc;
    private Context _context;

    public a(Context context){
        _context = context;
    }

    public void start(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, (LocationListener) this);

        new Timer().schedule(
            new TimerTask(){
                public void run() {
                    stop();
                }
            }
        ,System.currentTimeMillis(), 2*60*1000);
    }

    public void stop(){
        Log.d("states","stop");
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("states", "onLocationChanged()");
        lastloc = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }
}
```

Comment: how your code behaves? does it keep updating after the 2 minutes or stops way before that?

Comment: it keeps updating after 2 minutes and don't stop.

Comment: I believe your problem is not in this code

Comment: my problem is I don't know how fire stop() method after 2 minutes !! Timer().schedule() runs the TimerTask() in other thread and from there I can't fire current thread stop() method.

Comment: you have a compilation error?

Comment: try: a.this.stop(); or this.a.stop();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code of `Timer` again. Usually, the `Timer` code should be like:

```
Timer.schedule(TimerTask,
        delayTime); // delay a task before executed for the first time, in milliseconds
```

Because of your `delayTime` has been executed by using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, the `System` picks the current time in milliseconds since midnight, so that the `TimerTask` will be executed after millions millisecond.

Hence, use this code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do your thing here
        }
    }, 2*60*1000);
```

See this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) about the type of `Timer` you created.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by using handlers.

read this page: [Using Bundle Android to Exchange Data Between Threads](http://www.biemmeitalia.net/blog/bundle-android/)

*a.java*

```
public class a implements LocationListener{
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private Location lastloc;
    private Context _context;

    private Thread workingthread = null;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d("states","return msg from timer2min");
            if(msg.what==1){
                stop();
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    public a(Context context){
        _context = context;
    }

    public void start(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, (LocationListener) this);

        workingthread=new timer2min(mHandler);
        workingthread.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        Log.d("states","stop");
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("states", "onLocationChanged()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }
}
```

*timer2min.java*

```
public class timer2min extends Thread {
    private Handler hd;

    public timer2min(Handler msgHandler){
        hd = msgHandler;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2*60*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Message msg = hd.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = 1;
        hd.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```